# Excel formula to build a list based on multiple "OR" criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array, list

I have a formula that can build a list of product codes based on a set of item names ("ITEM1" and "ITEM2" in the example below). How can I do this using a cell range instead of listing each item name in my formula? Excel does not allow me to use a range within the curly braces {}.

My objective is to list all product codes for multiple items.

{=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$50=**{"ITEM1","ITEM2"}**,ROW($A$2:$A$50)),ROWS($E$1:E1))),"")}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your range was D1:D2;

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$50,$D$1:$D$2,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$50)),ROWS($E$1:E1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter Instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.